# ng-options with ng-init not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given this scenario this select doesn't initialize if the value doesn't exist in the repeater. It is posibile to display a value different from the ones in the repeater ?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ptongalex/h86kd4mz/)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="somethingHere2"/>
Select:
<select ng-init="somethingHere2 = options.default" 
        ng-model="somethingHere2" 
        ng-options="items for items in options.values">
</select>

$scope.workItem = 100;
$scope.options = {
  default:$scope.workItem,
  values:[1,2,3,4,5]
};
$scope.serviceValues = Service; // Service = .factory('Service',...)
```

Comment: No, it's not - why not add the value to the repeater?

Comment: eventully I will do this

Comment: Do directly `ng-model="options.default"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to add a single hard-coded `<option>` to the `<select>` which will be the default selected option, often used to have a "Please select..." or similar - note this must have a value="", i.e. an empty string:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="somethingHere2"/>
Select:
<select ng-init="somethingHere2 = options.default" 
        ng-model="somethingHere2" 
        ng-options="items for items in options.values">
    <option value="">Please select...</option>
</select>
```

This might allow you to do what you want - other than that, the whole point of ng-options is that it iterates over the supplied values and limits the select to those values, so you can't have values which are not in the array.

Comment: does this apply if my values come from a service ? (options.defaul = Service with $http)

Comment: because 1) my options come from a $http request (service), 2) I applied your code to my jsfiddle and doesn't work with normal $scope variables

Comment: @VladRadulescu Apologies - the value has to be empty (i.e. `value=""`) in order for it to work as a default value in the drop down list. I've updated to that effect. I don't think it should matter if the rest of the values are being derived from an HTTP request, though...